# How to remove /index.html

Tags: htaccess, redirects, apache, virtualhost, directory-index

How to make redirect /index.html -> `/` in Apache?

```
Redirect /index.html http://domain-name.com/
```

Is causeing infinite loop when opening home page.

Comment: You might want to check out this question on stackoverflow http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3771175/apache-htaccess-to-redirect-index-html-to-root-why-followsymlinks-and-rewriteb

Comment: Here the whole about the one you looking for

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3771175/apache-htaccess-to-redirect-index-html-to-root-why-followsymlinks-and-rewriteb

Answer (score 4):

It is most likely causing an infinite loop as they are the same. The default pages in Apache are `index.html` and `index.htm.`

If the browser does not request a file name the web server will return one of those files if it finds them.
So When you go to `http://domain-name.com` you are actually viewing `http://domain-name.com/index.html` just without `/index.html`

Answer (score 3):

Just do it the other way round, instead of redirecting to the domain `example.com`, tell the server which page to display when a user requests the domain directly.

In the .htaccess file you can write (this is the default anyway):

```
DirectoryIndex index.html
```

Now if somebody requests `http://example.com` the server will actually send back the `index.html` file, but the browser still displays `http://example.com`. If somebody requests `http://example.com/index.html` there is no reason not to deliver this page, as long as you do not link to this URL somewhere, nobody will ever request it in this form.

Answer (score 1):

From an SEO perspective, if example.com/ and example.com/index.html are the same, use canonical links to address it.